# Getting the time via Crontab to Laravel 4

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, cron

I have created an artisan command that fires a new Date which inserts into the database. What triggers this command is one of my cronjobs. Code below:

```
    public function fire(){

        $var = new MyModel;

        $var->datetime = new MongoDate();
        $var->name = 'Jess';
        $var->save();
    }
```

and my cronjob is:

```
* * * * * php /Applications/AMPPS/www/condo/laravel/artisan mycronjobcommand
```

Everything looks great and is perfectly working, however, I have some worries that the `new MongoDate()` date inserts into the mongodb is not precisely to the 0 milliseconds it is about 1 ish like below:

```
2014-05-11T15:22:01.806Z
2014-05-11T15:23:01.406Z
```

Is there a a way to have the milliseconds as close to the 0 as possible? Or even dead on the dot 0 millisecond? I am afraid if I have a huge database and the write speed will go over 1 minute.

I have tried to cronjob the unix timestamp into the artisan argument but the artisan reads it as a string (date) not the timestamp.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Linux runs several cron jobs in order or at the same time. If you want precision you would need to make a timer program which monitors the time and fires your script at 0ms.

NOTE: There are other problems such as the fact PHP takes time to start up, and Laravel can take 30-50ms to start up depending on what you load, which distorts your time from the 0ms you're aiming for.